# iOS - Actual device - appium scroll : Need to scroll to a particular element and click

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium

Problem: Automation with iOS Actual device using Appium, all i am trying is to scroll down to a particular element which is not in the current page and select that element./click on that element.

Used so far:

- used scrollTo("text") and scrollToexact("text") - came to know that this is depricated now in java-client . Just want to double confirm is it true?

  - did try to use the below,but still no luck

    MobileElement slider = driver
            .findElement(MobileBy
                    .IosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[0]"
                            + ".scrollToElementWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS 'Slider'\")"));
    assertEquals(slider.getAttribute("name"), "Sliders");

It would be helpful if some one could help me resolve this, also would like to do the scroll for android later as well, have not tried it yet.

Below is the code where i have used various techniques but still no success,the code runs launches the app,but does not scroll and select any element:

```
import java.io.File;

import java.net.URL;

import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;



import org.junit.AfterClass;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;



import io.appium.java_client.MobileBy;

import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement;



import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;



public class testfour {



public static IOSDriver driver;


@BeforeClass

public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {



DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

//capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);

capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");

capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone_6");

 capabilities.setCapability("udid", "840384833537f40d011032eaaf20a53705a451ce");

 capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "iOS");

 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "9.2.1");

 capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "MAC");


 capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);

  capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);


  driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }



   @Test

   public void test()  throws InterruptedException {


   System.out.println("TEST STARTED");


    //Make

   driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[6]/UIAStaticText[1]").click();

    System.out.println("TEST STARTED6 MAKE");

    //Select Audi and model a8

 driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[8]/UIAStaticText[1]").click();

  System.out.println("TEST STARTED5 AUDI");

driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIATableView[1]/UIATableCell[8]/UIAStaticText[2]").click();

     System.out.println("TEST STARTED4 MODEL");

 //driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[17]/UIAStaticText[1]").click();

    System.out.println("TEST STARTED3");

    //String Str = "A8";

      System.out.println("TEST STARTED2");



   //MobileElement slider = (MobileElement)    driver.findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[2]"+ ".scrollToElementWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS 'Slider'\")"));

   MobileElement slider = (MobileElement)  driver.findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[17]"+ ".scrollToElementWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS 'A8'\")"));

    System.out.println("TEST STARTED1");

    assertEquals(slider.getAttribute("A8"), "Sliders");

    System.out.println("TEST STARTED0");


  //  MobileElement table = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(".tableViews()[0]"));

  //  MobileElement slider = (MobileElement) table.findElement(MobileBy.IosUIAutomation(".scrollToElementWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS 'Slider'\")"));

 //   assertEquals(slider.getAttribute("name"), "Sliders");



   //driver.findElementByIosUIAutomation(".scrollToElementWithName(\""+ Str + "\")").click();

  //WebElement tableView = driver.findElementByIosUIAutomation(".tableViews() [2]");

  //((IOSElement) tableView).scrollTo("A8");

  //((IOSElement) tableView).scrollTo("A8").click();


    System.out.println("TEST STARTED1");


   //driver.execute("mobile: scroll", [{direction: 'down',     driver.findElementByXPath:  ("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[17]/UIAStaticText[1]"}]);

    //driver.scrollTo("A8").click();


    //JavascriptExecutor jes = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    //HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String> ();

     //scrollObject.put("direction", "down");

   //scrollObject.put("element",   (driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[17]/UIAStaticText[1]")));

    //jes.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);

  //jes.executeScript(arg0, arg1)

   //driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);

    //driver.switchTo()

    //jes.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",  driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATableView[2]/UIATableCell[17]/UIAStaticText[1]"));


          //driver.findElementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[7]").click();

    // driver.scrollToExact(text)

     //  driver.scrollTo("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[7]").click();



   //Select Model000

  driver.findElement(By.linkText("All Models")).click();     

  driver.findElement(By.linkText("AVALON")).click();

    //Click on Search button

   driver.findElement(By.id("search_btn")).click();       

  // Click on the Search Alert Bar

  driver.findElement(By.id("switchButton")).click();            

  //ex: for content-desc //Click on the Back button and navigate to home page

  driver.findElement(By.name("Navigate up")).click();

  //Now click on the Menu in the home page   

  driver.findElement(By.name("Navigate up")).click();          

  //Click on the Search Search under the menu item

   driver.findElementByLinkText("Saved Searches").click();      

   //get the text

  String text = driver.findElement(By.id("name_tv")).getText(); 

  System.out.println("Actual Text:"+text);


    System.out.println("Test has been completed");

   }



  private void assertEquals(String attribute, String string) {

  // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}



     @AfterClass

  public void tearDown()

  {

     driver.quit();

   }

       }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure that your question is complete as described here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You will get quicker and better responses on complete questions.

Comment: @All, Any suggestion on this? Still stuck up with this issue. Looking forward to some help

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is old, but came across it searching for a different problem and thought I could help.

What I do here is use Appium "swipe".

First, I get the size of my screen:

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
```

Then, I swipe the screen down:

```
driver.swipe(size.width / 3, (int) (size.height * 0.8), size.width / 3, (int) (size.height * 0.8) - 200, 300);
```

After swiping, I call a boolean method to look for the element which returns:

```
return driver.findElement(Bylocator).isDisplayed();
```

I have this swipe action/isDisplayed check wrapped in a FluentWait, but a simple while loop with some sort of timeout condition and the isDisplayed check would work too.

After the element has been swiped to and found, a simple click call will complete your request.
(Note: I use this process for iOS and Android, so it should work on both platforms for you, too.)

TL;DR - use driver.swipe, check if element is displayed. If not, swipe and check again. wrap in loop of your choice until element is found or loop timeout hits.